# Comparing numbers across several columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of prices on my Google sheet and am looking to write a script that will compare the prices on each row across several columns and show only the row with the lowest price.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about it. I'm guessing this is what it needs to do:

-compare number between columns
-clear cells that does not have the lowest price
-change text color of the lowest price
-repeat until the last row

Any tips on how to do this in Google apps script would be appreciated!

```
function PriceCompare() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
var datas = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  
var col1 = 14;
var col2 = 15;
var col3 = 16;

var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
var c1=c2=c3=co1=co2=co2=3; //starting row for all columns
var values = ss.getRange(3,14,lastrow,3).getValues();
for(c1=3;c2<values.length;c1++)
 for(c2=3;c2<values.length;c2++)
  for(c3=3;c3<values.length;c3++) {
   if(values[c1]<[c2] && [c1]<[c3])
     ss.getRange(c1, 14, 1).setFontColor('blue');
   elseif(values[c2]<[c1] && [c2]<[c3]) 
     ss.getRange(c1, 15, 1).setFontColor('blue');
   elseif(values[c3]<[c1] && [c3]<[c2]) 
     ss.getRange(c1, 16, 1).setFontColor('blue');
 }
}
```

The code above is intended to check across each row for three columns and color the lowest number blue. When I run the code it works for some rows but is  completely off for others. Sometimes it will color two rows.

I first wanted to have something that can compare prices on each row and just color the lowest price, then figure out how to clear the cells.

Comment: to make a valid question you need to show a coding attempt and a specific coding question about it. see spreadsheetApp.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what do you want to do, but if i understand your question correctly you want to add all cells in a row together and find the row with biggest result.

Anyway, next time post example of yours code as well ;)

So what i would do:

```
function adding() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_of_your_spreadsheet); //Your original spreadsheet

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    //first column will be empty for results
    var first = data[i][1];
    var second = data[i][2];
    //etc...

    var resoult = first + second;
    var cell = sheet.getRange("A"+(i+1)); //Empty column for resoults
    cell.setValue(resoult);
  }
}

function clearing_and_comparing(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_of_your_spreadsheet); //Your original spreadsheet

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var result1 = data[1][0];
    var result2 = data[2][0];

    if(result1>result2){
      sheet.deleteRow(2);
    }else{
      sheet.deleteRow(1);
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is what you want. (sorry for bad english :D)

Comment: Question has been updated - your interpretation of the problem was not correct. You can edit your answer now that the question is clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, it is much clearer now. But could you please add the spreadsheet as well? Because i am not sure if i get the range right. Thank you